# Polyglot Interpreters

Tags: code-challenge, interpreter, polyglot

### Challenge

1. Choose any number of languages. Call this set `L`.
2. Write a program so that running it in any language in L produces an interpreter for a **different** language in `L`.
   Each language in `L` must have **exactly one** interpreter for it. This is to prevent, for example, [Nothing](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Nothing) or [Text](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Text) being part of `L` and all interpreters being for that single language.
3. Your score is the number of bytes of your code divided by the number of languages in `L`. Lowest score wins.

### Rules

- Any language may have an interpreter for any other language -- it doesn't need to be one large cycle.
- An interpreter can input program code and input however you see fit.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
- Different versions of a language count as distinct (e.g. Python 3.4 and 3.5) but not patch versions (e.g. Python 3.4.1 and 3.4.4). *Thanks to [caird coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing) for this.*

### Example Submission *(clarified due to [Kaddath](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90841/kaddath)'s comment)*

````
# [Julia 1.0](https://julialang.org) and [Brainf***](https://esolangs.org/wiki/brainfuck), B bytes / 2 languages = B/2
```
#=
<julia interpreter written in brainf***>
[-][
=#
<brainf*** interpreter written in julia>
# ]
```
Julia 1.0: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/#julia1x)
Brainf***: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/#brainfuck)
Explanation:
When ran in Brainf***, the Brainf*** code is run. The `[-]` sets the current cell to zero, then we skip over the rest of the code using `[ ... ]` since we know the current cell is zero.
When ran in Julia, the `#= ... =#` marks a comment, letting the Brainf*** code not get executed. After that is the Brainf*** interpreter, then the final line would have an unmatched `]`, so it is commented out.
````

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833) and nice first question! For future reference, we recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get feedback on challenge ideas before posting them to main. This seems like a nice challenge on paper, but the practicalities of writing interpreters for languages any more complex than Turing tarpits means that this requires a lot of work to do for any non-trivial languages

Comment: If you're not sure what @cairdcoinheringaahing means by a [Turing tarpit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_tarpit), see the Wikipedia entry linked.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Ah, ok. Yes, most languages are rather complicated. In retrospect, the Sandbox would have been the way to go. Sorry!

Comment: @JeffZeitlin A Turing tarpit is a language in which technically everything is possible but nothing is easy (e.g. brainf***).

Comment: (Yes, I know; I didn't assume that you [as a new contributor] necessarily did.)

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Understood! I have been interested in code golf for a while -- I just happened to join PPCG recently. :)

Comment: I've done a little bit of editing to clear up the question - feel free to revert anything you dislike. Additionally, do different versions of a language (e.g. Python 2 and Python 3) count as different languages for `L`? If so, how about minor version (e.g. Python 3.4 vs Python 3.6, or even Python 3.4.1 vs Python 3.4.4)?

Comment: @caird coinheringaahing Edited to clarify that last point (patch versions don't count, but minor versions do).

Comment: I knew that languages like [Nothing](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Nothing) is disallowed. But how can this prevent using languages like [+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/%2B) (A programming language which doesn't support any I/O and all programs in it always halt)?

Comment: @tsh + would have to be in `L`, so you would have to use it to write an interpreter for another language. :)

Comment: I followed the consensus that emerged from the 2 existing answers before mine that the answer's code would **be** the interpreter for L1 when run in L2 (and vice-versa for 2 languages), intead of **outputting** the other language's interpreter, like it could be understood from your Example Submission.. Seeing you have commented an existing answer approvingly, I thought this is what you meant. But that could be clearer in your example

Comment: @Kaddath You are correct. I'll clarify the question.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly) `u` / [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + [jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 70 bytes = 35

```
from jelly import*
a=sys.argv
main(a[1],[*map(try_eval,a[2:])],'')
ŒV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z@tKD9XIQvEVsjMLcgvKtHiSrQtrizWSyxKL@PKTczM00iMNozVidbKTSzQKCmqjE8tS8zRSYw2sorVjNVRV9fkOjop7P///wVFmXklGuoeQKPydRTC84tyUhSBkokKtgqmXBDJRAjXDM4FAA) (Jelly)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1chKzUnp1IhM7cgv6hEiyvRtriyWC@xKL2MKzcxM08jMdowVidaKzexQKOkqDI@tSwxRycx2sgqVjNWR11dk@vopLD///9r6/@PNtQx0jGOBQA) (Python)

Both error after executing the other language.

This is a bit of a cheat tbh. Jelly has an "execute as Python" builtin, `ŒV`, and, as of [April 9, 2018](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/commit/4765fa6271be3ea89f1ae93454fc55dc733845b9), Jelly is a `pip`-installable package, meaning that we can just import it and run it.

### How they work

Jelly ignores every line except for the last, and just runs that:

```
ŒV - Main link. Takes a string on the left
ŒV - Execute the string as Python code
```

For some reason, I think because of the `[...]` in the above lines, there's some parsing error thrown afterwards.

For Python, we import the contents of the `jelly` package, read and evaluate the command-line arguments, then run the program in the first command-line argument with the values in the second and third arguments

Comment: Wow! How does the Jelly solution work? I'm surprised!

Comment: @KinuTheDragon I've added an explanation - `ŒV` is Jelly's "evaluate as Python" builtin

Comment: I've seen Jelly used to parse HTML, but this is surprising! :) +1

Answer (score 2):

## Windows Batch/Powershell 7, 38 bytes, 19 score

```
ls >$null&&cmd /c "$args"
pwsh -c "%*"
```

Assumes that there is no file named `ls` in current directory plus Powershell 7 executable `pwsh.exe` is in PATH.

It needs Powershell 7 because `&&` and `||` syntactic sugar was introduced in that version.

It first checks if any command is `ls`, `>$null` suppresses the output. If it succeeded we assume the interpreter is Powershell, so we execute Batch code and vice versa.

It generates some extra errors besides the STDOUT, but I think that's fine because @caird's answer also errors.

Answer (score 1):

## Windows Batch / [PHP](https://php.net/) < 8, 25 bytes, Score: 12.5

```php
php -r %1;echo`$argv[1]`;
```

[(cannot really) Try it online for PHP!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkgVhBt0hB1dA6NTkjP0ElsSi9LNowNsH6////ZalFAA) (it runs, but external scripts seem to be disabled, for security reasons I guess)

Cannot test Windows Batch in TIO and haven't found another site for it (makes sense actually) -> you can place the code in a `test.bat` file and run something like `test.bat "echo 42;"` to pass the PHP code as parameter

- Assumes that PHP executable is in PATH under the `php` command.
- in PHP below version 8, `php` and `r` are assumed string constants, and `-` `%` are operators, this part tries to calculate the result but does nothing with it. The rest of the code executes the argument as command-line code and outputs the result.
- in Windows Batch, executes the first argument received as PHP code and outputs the result. The rest of the code is considered as a second argument and is ignored.